# "undefined" or "null" which the Garbage Collector is in favor of

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

Suppose I create two objects:

```
var a = new SomeObject();
var b = document.getElementById("someElement");
/* Do something with those two object */
```

After do something with those two objects I need to clear them in case of memory leak.

The question is which one should I choose btween "null" and "undefined" that the Garbage Collector will prefer.

```
// firstly, remove DOM node
b.parentElement.remove(b);

// then clear the variants using "null" or "undefined"
a = null;
b = null;

/* or:
a = undefined;
b = undefined;
*/
```

Any comments will be appreciated!

Comment: FYI, added another paragraph to the answer that explains when you may need to do this.  For instance, I know your sample code is just made up code, but in those examples, `a` and `b` will fall out of scope once the function they're defined in returns.  At this time, whatever `a` and `b` referred to will be unreachable via `a` and `b`.  If you, e.g. ran setTimeout with an anonymous function that used `a` or `b` (closes on `a` or `b`) then whatever the point to will remain in memory until that callback is no longer runnable.  Hopefully u see the pattern :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The garbage collector works by keeping track of which objects are reachable by your code.  The idea is that if an object is not reachable, the block of memory it occupies can be freed without breaking your program.

One way in which an object can be reached is if it's assigned to a variable.  Assigning a new value to a variable that presently points to an object (e.g. by assigning `null` to `a`) will reduce the reference count on that object by one.  When this or any object's reference count is reduced to zero, it will qualify for garbage collection.

All that said, it's not really important what value you use to replace the value of a variable, as long as it's not some other object that would otherwise be garbage collected.  For this reason, both `undefined` and `null` will work.

Note that you only need to scrub variables like this if a variable remains reachable by your code after the function that the variable was declared in returns.  This could happen if an anonymous function closes on the variable, if the variable is "global" (tacked onto the `global` object or declared without the `var` keyword), or if the variable is actually a field on an object that's still reachable.